# Probability of tossing a coin 1000 times and coming up with heads

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have this problem on my final review sheet and was wondering if someone can go over it with me

You are tossing a fair coin 1000 times. Find what is the probability that it comes up heads

(a) $500$ times or less?

(b) $501$ times or more?

(c) $502$ times or more?

the sample space for tossing it once will be {H,T}=$\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It would help us give an appropriate answer if we knew what you had tried. Please add some information to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of heads shown on $n$ tosses of a fair coin is described by a binomial distribution, $H_n \sim Bin(n, p)$ where $p = 0.5$. The binomial distribution is described as $Pr(Bin(n, p) = k) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$.

The cumulative binomial distribution is then the sum of the individual values, but obviously if $n=1000$ you probably don't want to be evaluating those sums exactly. Instead, you're probably meant to apply the Central Limit Theorem to approximate the distribution with an appropriate Normal distribution, possibly with a finite continuity correction. I recommend you look through your notes to see if that's the case, and then to work out what that means in this case.